# Extra text added by external table by impala,hive in first row from csv

Tags: csv, hive, hdfs, impala, bigdata

I have many csv's with some rows and multiple columns. First cell is of id Ex: `c63-c5cf-44d7` and so on in S3 bucket. 
So I create external table on that location without skipping header as there is no header and first row also have actual values.

If i make `select *` from then first cell value get appended automatically with some text like

```
./Track.2017-02-06-12-11_ae55b12f.csv00006440000000000000000031413046064003015703 0ustar  rootrootc63-c5cf-44d7
```

Above string at last cell value after rootroot..
I tried to replace it regex_replace also tried regex_extract but it fails when apply with select query while fetching values.

When I import select id list in to csv it show many `?` marks.
Is it CSV header issue? OR its recommended to use Header while creating csv and avoid while creating external table.

Comment: Please show the external table definition

Comment: WE observed that as we have multiple files in tar.gz and then we create external table on that like below
Create external table temp (col1 type1,col2 type2.....)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3a://@BucketName;

We read that impala does not support for tar.gz ..When did using single csv in .gz it worked but not with .tar.gz

Is it really a reason for above issue?